# Ruby - ruby-debug terminating without error on 'if __FILE__ == $0'

Tags: ruby, debugging, ruby-debug

I'm trying to use ruby-debug to debug this script I've written and it keeps terminating on the line, `if __FILE__ == $0`. I step through each line before it, and then when it gets to that line it just quits. No errors or anything, it just quits. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually everything is working as it is supposed to. The `if __FILE__ == $0` idiom basically translates to "if this file is the running program", which it is not if run from the debugger. See e.g. the following thread on ruby-talk for a discussion of this issue:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/113859#new